# one controller for some models and views in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three models: add_customer_model, add_post_model and add_project_model. Also I have three views: add_customer.tpl, add_post.tpl and add_project.tpl. I want to make one controller for them. Here it is:

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ADD extends MX_Controller {

public $mname, $tag, $tpl;

function __construct()
{
    $this->mname=strtolower(get_class());// imya modulya               
    $this->tag=strtoupper($this->mname); // TAG v shablone   
} 


//add_customer
public function index()
{   
    include APPPATH."language/".LANG.".php";

    $userGROUP = $this->session->userdata('_userGROUP');
    if($userGROUP!=='Administrator')
    {
        show_404('page');
        exit; 
    }
    $this->load->model($this->mname.'/add_customer_model');
   // $model=$this->mname.'_model';
    //$this->$model->index($this->mname);
    $a['IsEnabled']=$LANGUAGE['IsEnabled']; 
    $a['Submit']=$LANGUAGE['Submit'];
    $a['Cancel']=$LANGUAGE['Cancel'];
    $a['Reset']=$LANGUAGE['Reset'];
    $a['Name']=$LANGUAGE['Name'];
    $a['Project Name']=$LANGUAGE['CustomerName'];
    $a['Customer Name']=$LANGUAGE['Customer Name'];

    $this->tp->assign($a);
    $this->tp->parse('CONTENT', $this->mname.'/add_customer.tpl');
}


//add_post
public function add_post()
{ 
    include APPPATH."language/".LANG.".php";

    $userGROUP = $this->session->userdata('_userGROUP');
    if($userGROUP=='Engineer')
    {
        show_404('page');
        exit; 
    }
    $this->load->model($this->mname.'/add_post_model');
   // $model=$this->mname.'_model';
    $this->$model->add_post($this->mname);
    $a['IsEnabled']=$LANGUAGE['IsEnabled']; 
    $a['Submit']=$LANGUAGE['Submit'];
    $a['Cancel']=$LANGUAGE['Cancel'];
    $a['Reset']=$LANGUAGE['Reset'];
    $a['Activity Name']=$LANGUAGE['Activity Name'];

    $this->tp->assign($a);
    $this->tp->parse('CONTENT', $this->mname.'/add_post.tpl');
}

//add_project   
public function add_project()
{ 
include APPPATH."language/".LANG.".php";

    $this->load->model($this->mname.'/add_project_model');
   // $model=$this->mname.'_model';
   // $this->$model->add_project($this->mname);
    $a['IsEnabled']=$LANGUAGE['IsEnabled']; 
    $a['Submit']=$LANGUAGE['Submit'];
    $a['Cancel']=$LANGUAGE['Cancel'];
    $a['Reset']=$LANGUAGE['Reset'];
    $a['Name']=$LANGUAGE['Name'];
    $a['SelectCustomer']=$LANGUAGE['SelectCustomer'];
    $a['Project Name']=$LANGUAGE['ProjectName'];
    $a['Manager']=$LANGUAGE['Manager'];
    $a['Customer']=$LANGUAGE['Customer'];
    $userGROUP = $this->session->userdata('_userGROUP');
    if ($userGROUP=='Administrator')
    $a['AddManager']='<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="AddNewManager()">+</button>';
    else
    $a['AddManager']='';
    $this->tp->assign($a);
    $this->tp->parse('CONTENT', $this->mname.'/add_project.tpl');
}
```

}

```
But in my browser I can see only add_customer page. But when I want to see add_post and add_project pages, it also shows me add_customer page. Where is a mistake?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->load->model($this->mname.'/'.$this->mname.'add_post_model');
```

This translates to:

```
$this->load->model('add/addadd_post_model');
```

Unusual setup. I suppose if you changed it to the following, it might work:

```
$this->load->model($this->mname.'/add_post_model');
```